# Aligning form input boxes in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I am attempting to have my form input text boxes all line up. However, they are unaligned and I have been unable to solve this. What should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(134, 210, 221)
}

.event{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.radio1{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.radio2{
    float: left;
}

.gender{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.required{
    color: red;
}

p{
    clear: both;
    
}

label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#date{
    float: left;
}

.submit{
    text-align: center;
}

input{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>

<form>
    <p class="event"><span class="required">*</span>Select Event:</p> 
    <div class="radio1">
    <p><input type="radio" id="stock">Stock</p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="modified">Modified</p>
    </div>
   
        <p><span class="required">*</span>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
        </p>
        <p><span class="required">*</span>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></p>
        <p><span class="required">*</span>Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"></p>
        <p><span class="required">*</span>City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></p>

        <p><span class="required">*</span>Province: <select name="selectprovince" id="selectprovince">Select Province
        <option value="provinces">...</option>
        <option value="provinces">AB</option>
        <option value="provinces">BC</option>
        <option value="provinces">MB</option>
        <option value="provinces">NB</option>
        <option value="provinces">NL</option>
        <option value="provinces">NT</option>
        <option value="provinces">NS</option>
        <option value="provinces">NU</option>
        <option value="provinces">ON</option>
        <option value="provinces">PE</option>
        <option value="provinces">QC</option>
        <option value="provinces">SK</option>
        <option value="provinces">YT</option>
</select></p>

<p><span class="required">*</span>Postal/Zip Code: <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal"></p>
<p><span class="required">*</span>Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>
<p><span class="required">*</span>Email: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>

<label for="date"><span class="required">*</span>Date of Birth</label>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date">


<p class="gender"><span class="required">*</span>Gender: </p> 
<div class="radio2">
<p><input type="radio">Male</p>
<p><input type="radio">Female</p>
<p><input type="radio">Other</p>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<p><span class="required">*</span>Boat Name: <input type="text" name="boat" id="boat"></p>

<p class="comments">Comments <textarea name="comments" form="form" id="comments" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea></p>
</div>

<p><span class="required">*</span>I agree to the waiver <input type="checkbox"> Yes </p>
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
</form>
      
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTML` **structure** is very important to understand and to learn how it works and how to put elements together. If you have a good HTML **structure**, it will be easy to edit and style.

One of your mistakes is that you put the `input` inside the `p`. So what **you should do** is put each row (elements group) in a `container` with `flex display`. and put them separated properly in a good **structure**. then give **all elements on the left**, the same `width` to align all right elements properly in a vertical line.

here I did that for the **first three groups** in your code. you can follow the same steps to do for the rest.

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(134, 210, 221)
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    min-width: fit-content;
    align-items: center;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100px;
    /* height: 10px; */
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.right {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 400px;
}

select {
    display: flex;
}

.event{
    /* display: inline;
    float: left;
    clear: both; */
}

.radio1{
    /* display: inline;
    float: left; */
}

.radio2{
    /* float: left; */
}

.gender{
    /* display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both; */
}

.required{
    color: red;
}

p{
    /* clear: both; */
    
}

label{
    /* display: block;
    float: left; */
}
#date{
    /* float: left; */
}

.submit{
    text-align: center;
}

input{
    /* display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    clear: both; */
}
```

```html
    
    <form>
      <div class="container">
        <p class="event left"><span class="required">*</span>Select Event:</p> 
       <div class="radio1 right">
          <p><input type="radio" id="stock">Stock</p>
          <p><input type="radio" id="modified">Modified</p>
       </div>
      </div>
       
      <div class="container">
        <p class="left">
          <span class="required">*</span>
          Last Name: 
        </p>
        <input class="right" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
      </div>
         
      <div class="container">
        <p class="left">
          <span class="required">*</span>
          First Name: 
        </p>
        <input class="right" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
      </div>
         
          <p class="left">
            <span class="required">*</span>
            Address: 
            <input class="right" type="text" name="address" id="address"></p>
          <p class="left">
            <span class="required">*</span>
            City: 
            <input class="right" type="text" name="city" id="city"></p>
  
          <p class="left"><span class="required">*</span>
            Province: 
            <select class="right" name="selectprovince" id="selectprovince">Select Province
              <option value="provinces">...</option>
              <option value="provinces">AB</option>
              <option value="provinces">BC</option>
              <option value="provinces">MB</option>
              <option value="provinces">NB</option>
              <option value="provinces">NL</option>
              <option value="provinces">NT</option>
              <option value="provinces">NS</option>
              <option value="provinces">NU</option>
              <option value="provinces">ON</option>
              <option value="provinces">PE</option>
              <option value="provinces">QC</option>
              <option value="provinces">SK</option>
              <option value="provinces">YT</option>
            </select>
          </p>
    <select>
    <p><span class="required">*</span>Postal/Zip Code: <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal"></p>
    <p><span class="required">*</span>Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>
    <p><span class="required">*</span>Email: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>
    
    <label for="date"><span class="required">*</span>Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    
    
    <p class="gender"><span class="required">*</span>Gender: </p> 
    <div class="radio2">
      <p><input type="radio">Male</p>
      <p><input type="radio">Female</p>
      <p><input type="radio">Other</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
      <p><span class="required">*</span>Boat Name: <input type="text" name="boat" id="boat"></p>
      
      <p class="comments">Comments <textarea name="comments" form="form" id="comments" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea></p>
    </div>
    
    <p><span class="required">*</span>I agree to the waiver <input type="checkbox"> Yes </p>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
    </form>
```